# Java KeyListener Control

Tags: java, swing, jtextfield, keylistener

I use Key Listener to read an imput from user but i have an issue. First of all i read to JTextField "Please enter your name". If user enters a name for example John it changes to John. But if user enters invalid character for example **"7"** I want to write **"Please enter your name"** but it writes ***"Please enter your name7"***. It is going on until give a right input. How can I correct them??

```
public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
                int ascii = (int)e.getKeyChar();
                if((ascii >= 65 && ascii <=122) || (ascii <= 351 && ascii >= 199 )){
                    if(TextField1.getText().equals("Please enter your name"))
                        TextField1.setText("");
                }
                else
                    TextField1.setText("Please enter your name");   
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Variable names should NOT start with an upper case character.

```
if((ascii >= 65 && ascii <=122) || (ascii <= 351 && ascii >= 199 )){
```

Don't use magic numbers. If you are checking for lower/upper case alphabetic characters, then use methods from the `Character` class like `isLetter(...)`

Don't use a KeyListener it is an old API. Swing has newer an better API's. For example your logic won't work if text is pasted to the text field. Use a `JFormattedTextField` or a `DocumentFilter` to check for valid data as text is typed. See the section from the Swing tutorial on [How to Write a Document Filter](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/generaltext.html#filter) and [How to Use Text Fields](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/textfield.html) for more information.

I don't recommend placing text in the text field for a prompt. For a different approach check out [Text Prompt](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2009/11/29/text-prompt/)

> but it writes "Please enter your name7".

The reason that happens is because the keyTyped event is generated before the Document is updated with the typed text. To execute the setText() method last you can wrap that statement in a SwingUtiltities.invokeLater(...).

I don't recommend this approach for all the reasons given above.

Comment: Thanks for helping :) I get almost fell asleep while coding so i missed the rule. I m new at Windows Form App so im going to learn them :) I changed jtextfield to formattedfield. I will continue tomorrow. Thanks a lot

Answer (score 2):

Never use a KeyListener with a JTextComponent such as a JTextArea. Instead one option is to use either a DocumentListener or a DocumentFilter that have been added to the component's Document. If you want to completely prevent the user from entering the invalid character, then the DocumentFilter could work well. Another option is to attach an [InputVerifier](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/InputVerifier.html) to the component that kicks in when the user tries to leave the text component.

For example

```
import java.awt.event.FocusAdapter;
import java.awt.event.FocusEvent;
import javax.swing.*;
import javax.swing.text.JTextComponent;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class MyTextField extends JPanel {
    private static final String DEFAULT_TEXT = "Please enter your name";
    private static final int COLUMNS = 20;
    private JTextField textField = new JTextField(DEFAULT_TEXT, COLUMNS);

    public MyTextField() {
        add(new JLabel("Name:"));
        add(textField);
        add(new JButton("Submit"));

        textField.addFocusListener(new TextFocusListener());
        textField.setInputVerifier(new MyInputVerfier());
    }

    private class TextFocusListener extends FocusAdapter {
        @Override
        public void focusGained(FocusEvent e) {
            JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) e.getComponent();
            if (textComp != null) {
                textComp.selectAll(); // so can change all text
            }
            super.focusGained(e);
        }
    }

    private class MyInputVerfier extends InputVerifier {

        @Override
        public boolean verify(JComponent input) {
            String text = ((JTextComponent) input).getText();
            if (!text.replaceAll("\\d", "").equals(text)) {
                return false;
            }
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean shouldYieldFocus(JComponent input) {
            if (!verify(input)) {
                JTextComponent textComp = (JTextComponent) input;
                textComp.setText(DEFAULT_TEXT);
                textComp.selectAll();
                return false;
            }
            return super.shouldYieldFocus(input);
        }

    }

    private static void createAndShowGui() {
        MyTextField mainPanel = new MyTextField();

        JFrame frame = new JFrame("MyTextField");
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.getContentPane().add(mainPanel);
        frame.pack();
        frame.setLocationByPlatform(true);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                createAndShowGui();
            }
        });
    }
}
```